# What could be a security issue in this Perl?

Tags: perl, security

```
$transfer_amount = GetTransferAmount();
$balance = GetBalanceFromDatabase();

if ($transfer_amount < 0) {
    FatalError("Bad Transfer Amount");
}

$newbalance = $balance - $transfer_amount;
if (($balance - $transfer_amount) < 0) {
    FatalError("Insufficient Funds");
}

SendNewBalanceToDatabase($newbalance);
NotifyUser("Transfer of $transfer_amount succeeded.");
NotifyUser("New balance: $newbalance");
```

Could anybody explain to me if there is a security issue with this code?

Comment: What makes you think that there is an issue? If you want a security code review you are at the wrong place. This one is for specific programming questions "Is there something wrong, if yes what?" is far too broad.

Comment: I as a user would probably be annoyed by the fact that I get money taken from my account and am told about the new balance - but the transfer I asked for is never done, which probably causes the recipient to complain at some point. Wouldn't call that a security issue however...

Comment: @Yunnosch, `FatalError` probably throws an exception, but it's definitely a good of you to verify that assumption :)

Comment: @Barominos, You probably don't want to allow transfers of $0 either.

Comment: @Barominos Maybe learn about the domain you want to implement. There is a good reason that finance has implemented the ledger and a balance is merely a sum over the ledger.

Comment: @ikegami I do not get you. I was referring to the successful complete execution of the whole shown code. It ends with my new balance being sent, but not a new balance to the recipient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Problem 1

A very important security mechanism in financial transaction is the ability to perform audits. There's no indication that this code leaves behind any kind of paper trail. One shouldn't just update the balance, but also create a record of the transaction.

### Problem 2

That code suffers from a race condition. Consider what happens if they are two concurrent actions.

```
Process 1                                         Process 2
===============================================   ===============================================
$xfer_amt = GetTransferAmount();
$balance = GetBalanceFromDatabase();

if ($xfer_amt < 0) {
    FatalError("Bad Transfer Amount");
}

                                                  $xfer_amt = GetTransferAmount();                      
                                                  $balance = GetBalanceFromDatabase();

                                                  if ($xfer_amt < 0) {
                                                      FatalError("Bad Transfer Amount");
                                                  }

                                                  $newbalance = $balance - $xfer_amt;
                                                  if (($balance - $xfer_amt) < 0) {
                                                      FatalError("Insufficient Funds");
                                                  }

$newbalance = $balance - $xfer_amt;
if (($balance - $xfer_amt) < 0) {
    FatalError("Insufficient Funds");
}

SendNewBalanceToDatabase($newbalance);
NotifyUser("Transfer of $xfer_amt succeeded.");
NotifyUser("New balance: $newbalance");

                                                  SendNewBalanceToDatabase($newbalance);
                                                  NotifyUser("Transfer of $xfer_amt succeeded.");
                                                  NotifyUser("New balance: $newbalance");
```

(Renamed a variable so the code would fit better on the screen.)

The database will only end up being deducted for one of the transactions.

Doing this right gets even more complicated as you incorporate a fix for the first problem because you need to make sure the balance is always in sync with transaction records (taking into consideration the possibility of concurrent transactions, network failures, power outages, etc).

### Problem 3

Where do the funds ago? In most scenarios, there's a possibility that the doing something with the withdrawn funds fails. If so, instead of withdrawing the funds, you probably should be reserving them (marking them unavailable), and only withdrawing the funds once they have actually been used.

Comment: You can also improve performance and reduce the potential time frame for the race condition occurring by fetching the balance after checking the transfer amount is positive.